# Excel Macro Sometimes Breaks?

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a macro to duplicate a excel spreadsheet however when its run once it won't run again?

```
Sub Add_Week()
    'copy worksheet
    Dim test As Worksheet
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set test = ActiveSheet

    'extend date
    jamesdata = Range("D2")
    Firstdate = DateValue(jamesdata)
    seconddate = DateAdd("w", 7, Firstdate)
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = seconddate

    'change sheet name
    newname = Range("D2").Text
    test.Name = newname

End Sub
```

Comment: What error message do you get? and on which line?

Comment: runtime error 1004 cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet.... but I rename the sheet at the bottom? :(

Comment: You're copying sheet1 every time, so your final sheet name will be the same every time, unless you have altered D2 on Sheet1 (which this code doesn't do).

Comment: how do I change that>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
Sub Add_Week()

    Dim newDate As String

    'Copy the last sheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'Extend date
    newDate = DateAdd("w", 7, DateValue(Range("D2")))

    'The main problem is here, because sheet name can't accept "/, \ and single quote"
    'Return value by "DateAdd" method include slash by default.
    'So, I change it to "dd-mmm-yy" format. If you need others, modify format.
    'But it need to valid for sheet name.

    'Change data format to desire format (8-Jul-15)
    newDate = Format(newDate, "dd-mmm-yy")

    'Set date value
    Range("D2") = newDate

    'Change sheet name
    ActiveSheet.Name = newDate

End Sub
```